# Random Drives Appear in Computer/Devices and Drives

Tags: windows-10, usb, devicesanddrives

On my computer (Dell Studio 540 Desktop; Windows 10 Home N Build 17134), I have random drives appear under the main C drive but there's nothing plugged into the USBs. It's more of a nuisance than anything else. Do you why this could be happening?

[image: Random Drives in My Computer]

Comment: You should state the model of the computer. A guess is, they are memory card readers being exposed as empty drives. What happens when you attempt to open them?

Comment: @jww, just edited the above so as to state my computer's model. When I attempt to open them, it says "Please insert a disk into USB Drive (Drive:)".

Comment: It sounds like [File Explorer is not hiding empty USB drives, despite setting to 'hide empty drives](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/file-explorer-is-not-hiding-empty-usb-drives/96b30c80-02ea-46c8-ae1a-78d820f6ea1a).

Comment: Thank you @jww! Even though "Hidden Drives" was checked, I had the "Show Hidden Files, Folders and Drives" radio button enabled. Disabling that radio button fixed the issue.